# Deleting an Entity based on Attribute in WEKA

Tags: weka

I am doing association mining on a dataset I got from the WEKA website about hypothyroidism.

Each entity is a person. Each person has an attribute called class which can contain {negative, primary_hypothyroidism, secondary_hypothyroidism}

```
class = {negative, primary_hypothyroidism, secondary_hypothyroidism}
```

I want to delete the whole person that has negative. How do I do this inside WEKA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a filter called **"RemoveWithValues"** that will do what you ask.

If you are using the Weka GUI you can do the following:

1. Select the filter under filters > unsupervised > instance > RemoveWithValues
2. Click the box that contains the text describing the filter.
3. Identify the "attributIndex" (the index where your class is held).
4. Identify the "nominalIndices" (in your case it would be first).
5. Click Apply!

If you are using Java code you can read up on applying filters [here](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code).